# Is there any way to stop dropdown overlapping the header in react material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, dropdown, overlap

Is there any way to stop dropdown overlapping the dark header showing in [Dropdown Overlaps Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9nB.png) in react material ui (Menu List, Menu Item).

```
.MuiList-root .MuiList-padding .css-h4y409-MuiList-root {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

I tried z-index , but no luck.

Comment: try adding top:0; rigth:0;

Comment: `Z-index` only works for positioned elements (for example `position: absolute`) and relative to other elements that are found within the same parent.

Comment: Please provide code sample, because we can not help you like that.